# How do I get the input value from modal body and insert to database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I have a button where the user clicks "DECLINE" and a modal will show containing the following:

```
<div class="modal-body"> 
    <form action="declineAnnouncementReq.php" method="POST">
         <div class="control-group form-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <label>Please specify your reason:</label><br>
                <textarea rows="10" cols="100" name="reason" class="form-control" id="reason" style="resize:none"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </form>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="javascript:decline_id(<?php echo $row[0]; ?>) " class="btn btn-danger">DECLINE</a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

And after they input the reason, they should click "DECLINE" again from the modal footer. This "DECLINE" button inside the modal is for the deleting of the data they decided to decline, and at the same time the reason they input will insert into another table in the database. But when I click the button, it just deletes the data, but the reason doesn't insert into the database.

`declineAnnouncementReq.php`

```
 <?php include_once ('dbcontroller.php');           
        if(isset($_GET['decline_id']))
        {
            $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $reason = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['reason']);

            $res=mysqli_query ($conn,"SELECT sender_id FROM announcement_requests WHERE id=".$_GET['decline_id']);
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);
            $sender_id = $row['sender_id'];

            $delete = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM announcement_requests WHERE id=".$_GET['decline_id']);
            if ($delete){
                $insert = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT into pres_rec VALUES(id,'$sender_id','$reason','declined', '$date')");
                header("Location: requests.php");
            }
        }
    ?>
```

I know I don't have a submit button, but I don't know where should I place it? Or how will I combine it with the javascript in my `<a href="javascript:decline_id(<?php echo $row[0]; ?>) " class="btn btn-danger">DECLINE</a>` inside the modal footer?

EDIT: My javascript code for my decline_id

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function decline_id(id) {
        if(confirm('Are you sure you want to decline this request?'))
        {
            window.location.href='../admin/declineAnnouncementReq.php?decline_id='+id;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: please post your javascript code for the `decline_id` function. I bet that it's not properly serializing and submitting the form for you.

Comment: hi sir. i just  posted my javascript code. @JeffPuckettII

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by setting `window.location.href='...` in your `decline_id` function, you are merely redirecting the user to a new page without submitting any of the `form` data.

one solution would be to use the [`submit()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp) function.

firstly, you can retain using the `decline_id` in the query string by printing it out in your php `form` `action`, and make sure to give your `form` an `id` as this will make it easier to select for submission.

```
<form id="myForm" action="../admin/declineAnnouncementReq.php?decline_id=<?php echo $row[0]; ?>" method="POST">
```

next you could submit the form inside your `decline_id` function

```
function decline_id(id) {
    if(confirm('Are you sure you want to decline this request?'))
    {
        document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: this one's better, thank you sir. but it still didn't do the insert query.

Comment: this is what it shows `Column count doesn't match value count at row 1` not really sure it means?

Comment: now it's working. obviously my insert query has an error, fixed it and replaced with this line `$insert = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT into pres_noti (id, user, reason, noti_status, date) VALUES(id,'$sender_id','$reason','declined', '$date')") or die(mysqli_error($conn));` Thank you Sir! :D